# string comparison in windows gawk

Tags: awk

I am using gawk in a windows batch script.
To read a file that has two columns, e.g.,

```
WIDHT 1200
```

I use the following command:

```
gawk '{if($2==1200) print $1,$2}' filename
```

It runs OK, but if I use the following command to extract numbers by comparing strings, it fails

```
gawk '{if($1==WIDTH) print $1,$2}' filename
```

My question is how to compare strings in gawk?

Comment: You need to quote: `"WIDTH"`. I'm not sure how batch will handle the quotes though.

Comment: `$1==WIDTH` is comparing the contents of the 1st field with the contents of the variable `WIDTH`; as dan has mentioned, wrap the *string* in double quotes, eg: `$1=="WIDTH"`

Comment: Your input file apparently uses `WIDHT` while your code uses `WIDTH`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
gawk '$1=="WIDTH"'
```

Or in slightly longer, more explicit form:

```
gawk '$1=="WIDTH" {print $1, $2}'
```

In the first form, the condition is `$1=="WIDTH"` without any action, the default action is to print out the whole line.

In the second form, the action is more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

or u can make it both short and explicit at the same time :

```
gawk 'NF = 2 * ("WIDTH" == $!_)'
```

=

```
WIDTH 1200
```

This would force trim the fields down to just `$1 + $2` regardless of how many there were in the input line.